# Could not open X display Unable to init server: Could not connect

Tags: raspbian

I am currently working with a Raspberry Pi Model B running Raspbian. I have to display a web page on a screen using the uzbl-browser but this error is occurring:

```
gtk-launch uzbl-browser
** (gtk-launch:26369): WARNING **: Could not open X display
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gtk-launch:26369): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :1
```

Comment: Are you using SSH to connect to the Pi?

Comment: yes i am using ssh, but i have tried using display as well.

Comment: When directly conected to the Pi is it running the graphical desktop or the command line?

Comment: its command line because i am using RASPBIAN JESSIE LITE.

Comment: The error message is because you are not running  the graphical desktop and as a result there is no value for display. I think you are going to need the full Raspbian and to do it over SSH you will need to forward the x window.

Comment: I have install uzbl-browser and screenly-ose is using same and they can do it over jessie lite. I am new to pi but I have to do  this. is there any guideline for this kind installation

Comment: see this https://github.com/wireload/screenly-ose/blob/9ee0b8cc438cd6fa4b4c3b6d37590a2bbfabd900/ansible/roles/system/tasks/main.yml

Comment: *If* you want to show the GUI on the remote screen (connected to the Pi I presume) you need to set the display variable before starting the GUI-application. Similar to this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh

Comment: @SteveRobillard If you are using `ssh` from a graphical desktop you still need to add the `-X` option along with ssh in order to able to allow the remote application to use it. Like `ssh -X remote-computer-name`

Comment: I have just found a problem and successfully run that what I needed.

Comment: You should answer your own question or if it is unlikely to help others (a typo or misconnection) delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is I didn't install `matchbox` for the window manager and I had also not installed `lightdm`.

After that I set the display variable to `export DISPLAY=:0` and it is now working.

Comment: If this is the solution to your problem, you should mark this as the answer (click the tick under the down arrow on the left)